# Does duplicate content/links make content more findable?

Tags: navigation, information-architecture

We're having a bit of a disagreement of where certain content belongs on our company's website.

We have an Events page, where upcoming events are listed. However, this page was traditionally for events that we would physically be at - not webinars.

We also have a Resources page that has become a place where we dump stuff that doesn't exactly fit into the site's structure or doesn't really belong on another page.

Some people think that adding the webinars to the Events page is bad because users won't think Events when(if) they're searching for webinars on our website. They think the webinars should be its own page, so that people can easily find them. However, if this webinars page was created, I'm sure it will be nested in the Resources page mentioned above, thus not solving the problem.

What's the argument against having the same content in 2 places just for the sake of findability?

Answer (score 1):

#### User taxonomy is different from company taxonomy

This is a common trap in UX design.  Companies may organize their products a certain way, but may fail to understand how users perceive their products.

- For example: a company may organize its products by `category` (shoes, pants, shirts) but users may prefer to find and discover products by `brand` and by `color`.

The correct UX priority here is to **help the user find or discover the right event**. Then work backwards from that to figure out a low-friction UX flow that helps them do that.

- Once you move to user-centric navigation, you will find that **it's okay to have multiple paths to the same content**.  It's also OK to have the same content appear in different views.
- Any decent content management system will enable you to display the same content in different formats and places.

In your case, if it's reasonably likely that some users will be looking for `Events`, but other users will be looking for `Resources` and you think the events could be useful to them, then having the content appear twice is good UX practice!